# Why does next_permutation skip some permutations?

Tags: c++, permutation

Why doesn't this simple function output all permutations of the inputted 5 letter string? I think there should be 120 and it only outputs 90.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Creates permutation lists for strings
vector<string> createdcombos2(string letters)
{ 
    vector<string> lettercombos;    

    cout << "Letters are: " << letters << endl; //input string

    do 
        lettercombos.push_back(letters);        
    while(next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));    

    cout <<"Letter combos: " << endl;  //print out permutations 
    for (auto i : lettercombos)
        cout << i << endl;
    cout << endl << lettercombos.size() << endl; //number of permutations

    return lettercombos;
}


int main() 
{
    string letters = "gnary"; 
    vector<string> lettercombos;

    lettercombos = createdcombos2(letters);
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To return all permutations in a loop until next_permutation returns false, the vector must be sorted before the start of the loop. [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) returns the permutations in ascending order. So if you start off with an unsorted vector, it will begin part way through the series of permutations.

```
std::sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());
do 
    lettercombos.push_back(letters);        
while(next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end()));
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to sort the input, `next_permutation` will return the next permutation in lexicographical order. Because the input permutation: **"gnary"** is lexicographically "larger" than a permutation such as **"angry"**, those "smaller" permutations will never be reached.

You can sort the string using `std::sort()`

Answer (score 13):

As some of the previously made answers state, if you want to use the `bool` return value of `std::next_permutation` to stop the iterations, you have to make sure that you start from a "sorted" permutation. Otherwise, your cycle will terminate prematurely.

This is not absolutely necessary though.

Permutations enumerated through `std::next_permutation` form a *cyclic sequence* without a beginning or an end, which means that you can call `std::next_permutation` indefinitely and it will cycle through the same sequence of 120 permutations again, again and again. This means that you can start from absolutely any permutation in that cycle. You just have to remember your starting permutation and watch for the moment this permutation appears again. The very moment you arrive at your original permutation the iteration is over. In your case it will expectedly take 120 calls to `std::next_permutation`.

For example, the following code prints all 5-letter permutations for `"abcde"` set even though it starts from a completely arbitrary one

```
std::string start = "cadeb", current = start;
do
  std::cout << current << std::endl;
while (std::next_permutation(current.begin(), current.end()), current != start);
```

One can note though that comparing permutations at each iteration of the cycle is more expensive than using the return value of `std::next_permutation` (which comes "for free" from the innards of the algorithm), so if you are happy with the solution that pre-sorts the starting permutation, then it is indeed a more efficient way to do it.

Alternatively, if you know the exact number of permutations in the cycle (120 in this case), you can simply call `std::next_permutation` exactly that number of times (as suggested in @Potatoswatter's answer).

Answer (score 7):

The return `bool` value of `next_permutation` is like an overflow condition or a carry bit. It's `false` when it advances from the last permutation back to the first, in lexicographical order. But it still does advance, unconditionally.

If you know there are exactly 120 permutations, you can ignore the return value and just loop blindly:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 120; ++ i ) {
    lettercombos.push_back(letters);        
    next_permutation(letters.begin(), letters.end());
}
```

Comment: It will be 120 only if all 5 letters are different. (Just a noteworthy comment)

Comment: Thanks @Potatoswatter. This answer was painfully interesting to me :)  Before knowing this, I wrote some [silly] functions to turn the input vector into an enumerated map and then I permuted over the keys(from 0 to the size of the input vector) to get permutations of values !